# dropdown not retaining selected value on submit

Tags: php, ajax

this is a dynamic dropdown and here's my code on ajax/php:

```
function populateSubCategory(str){
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "";
return;
} else { 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
//for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
//for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("subcategory").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/getSubCategory.php?value="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
 }
```

getSubCategory.php:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
$selected = ($row['id'] == $_POST['subcategory']) ? ' selected' : "";   
echo "<option value=".$row['id']. $selected.">".$row['subcategory']) ."      </option>"; 
}
```

problem is, after submitting, it does not retain the selected item on the dropdown list. I've already tried this code but it does not work as well:

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    if($_POST['subcategory']==$row['id']) { 
        echo "<option selected>".$row['subcategory']."</option>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<option>".$row['subcategory']."</option>"; 
    }
```

What to do? Pls help, I'm stuck on this..

Comment: You are submitting the ajax by get.What's that $_POST['subcategory']?

Comment: I'm a beginner in php/ajax, do you both have a recommended solution on how to do this?

Comment: I think your select box is not getting populated with your response text as there is a issue when select options are updated via ajax. Make your structure like - <div id="selectResponse"><select id="subcategory"><option></option></select></div> and send the whole selectbox from ajax response and populate into div (document.getElementById("selectResponse").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;)

Answer (score 1):

You submitted using the ajax call rt. So you should pass the subcategory value to the server side. And also you specifies the method as GET, and called using POST ($_POST['subcategory']).

Comment: yes, value is pass to the server side, done this: $val = intval($_GET['value']); I normally just used: <input type="text" name="category" value="<?php echo $category = (isset($_POST['category'])) ? $category: "";?>"> to keep the text on the input field after user hit submit, but having a hard time doing this on dropdown..

Comment: I've tried changing POST to GET like this: $selected = $row['id'] == $_GET['val'] ? ' selected' : "";  
echo "<option value=".$row['id']. $selected.">".$row['subcategory']) ."</option>";  but no luck so far.. :(

Comment: What you got when echoed $_GET['value']?

Comment: this code: $val = intval($_GET['value']) returns whatever the id of the option value selected on the first dropdown. the code I posted above works on the first dropdown even after submit, it retains the value of the selected item, but not on the second and third dropdown. How can I store the selected value and retrieve it afterwards? I still do not have an idea on how to do this..

Comment: I'd also tried $_SESSION['subcategory'] and $_REQUEST['subcategory'] to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

thanks to your comments.. I've managed to display the selected value in the dropdown by using this jquery method:

```
$('#subcategory').on('change', function() {
var selectedSub = $('#subcategory :selected').text();
```

then echo the text in the hidden input field, so on submit, I can do this:

```
$subcategory = $_POST['hiddeninputfield'];
```

however, this leads to another problem, after submit or post, the dropdown selection is not retained. I would like user to still select or change whatever is in the dropdown list...